# Can someone tell me what this font is?

Tags: fonts

[image]Can someone tell me what this font is?

I tried finding it for the past 3 days and need help.

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to add the picture

Comment: You guys can at least wait for him to add the picture before you downvote

Comment: Hoe do I add the picture?

Comment: Figured it out.

Comment: I don'y know what you mean?

Comment: I still don't know what the font name is...and why are you answering in that tone?.... if you don't know a no comment or I don't know would be more helpful and polite that being arrogant

Comment: I thought you meant you figured out what the font was

Comment: Also text doesn't have a tone. It all sounds like a robot talking in monotone. Thats what internet speech sounds like. Unless it's in all caps. Then its yelling

Comment: No, I need to know what the font is

Comment: It looks like it was hand drawn but I could be wrong. Are you absolutely sure it's a font?

Comment: yes it is a font

Comment: How are you sure it is a font?

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought it was hand drawn but it is not.

It is a font with a filter over it.

It's not exact at all but it looks similar to [Brannboll](https://www.dafont.com/brannboll.font?text=good+tidings+of+comfort+and+joy&psize=l)

With filters over it similar to what was acheived [in this answer.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/101432/104169)

[image]

Comment: Other than the size and applied texture, the Ds Gs Is Fs and Os all look identical to me in their base shape. There appears to be some possible Open Type ligature use to apply swashes and flourishes, but it clearly looks like a font to me. *I don't know what font.* But I'd bet it's *not* hand drawn.

Comment: @Scott looking at this closer, you are right. 
The weird filter over the text made me think the characters looked different especially near the loop in the g.